# Java - Instance variables or method local variables are stays more time in the memory

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection

I have a silly problem in my mind to clarify. see below code. **Ex 1**, I create an instance of `MySecondClass` and use it in each method. Where I do not create an instance each time, in methods whenever I want it.

But in **Ex 2** I create instances of `MySecondClass` inside each method.

I want to know which implementation is good in terms of memory consumption (`garbage collection`) and good performance?

**Ex 1**.

```
 public class MyClass {

   private MySecondClass var1 = new MySecondClass ();


   public void doSomthing(){
      var1 .DoMultiply();
   }


   public void doAnotherThing(){
      var1 .DoCount();
   }


}
```

**Ex 2**

```
  public class MyClass {




     public void doSomthing(){

        MySecondClass mySec = new MySecondClass ();
        mySec.DoMultiply();
     }


     public void doAnotherThing(){

        MySecondClass mySec = new MySecondClass ();
        mySec.DoCount();

     }


 }
```

---

### UPDATE

Ok to complete the code I add the caller class.

```
public class Caller {

  public static void main(String arg[]){

    MyClass myClass = new MyClass ();  // first instance
    myClass.doSomthing();

    MyClass myClass2 = new MyClass ();   // second instance
    myClass2.doAnotherThing();

  }

}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you need to create a new instance (which obviously needs to be garbage collected each time) for each method call?

Comment: @zapl No, There is no reason. But Want to know which way is the best.

Comment: So what's the recommendation? Use Ex 1 or Ex 2

Answer (score 0):

Both has the same memory consumption (`O(1)`) but the latter gives more work to the garbage collector since after each method run `MySecondClass` becomes eligible for garbage collection.

The first option makes sense if your methods are functional and you can't mess up the state of `var1` (`MySecondClass`).

So basically without more information it is hard to tell which one to choose.

Comment: same memory consumption, how??

Comment: In second example he is creating two objects while in 1st one only 1 then how the memory consumption is equal?

Comment: And I think this O(1) notation is used for Time complexity not for space.

Comment: The reference to `MySecondClass` gets cleared up after each call so it won't occupy the memory.

Comment: The `O(1)` notation is used for *time* ***and*** space complexity as well.

Comment: Agreed it cleared on method termination but this is the task of GC. Here my point is memory consumption. As we know GC invocation is not in our hand.

Comment: Ex2 can have a higher memory consumption if you call those methods in rapid succession or in parallel in a multi-threaded scenario. GC is not instant and the instances will persist in memory a bit after each method call (unreachable and eligible for GC). It can on the other hand consume less memory if you never call those methods / when the GC has cleared them. Ex1 will always have 1 instance in memory, Ex2 will have 0..n (dead) instances depending on use.

Comment: May be I am wrong but I have heard that method local variables are eligible for GC when the method complete. So isn't it the good way? But it is low performance as I create new instance each time.

Comment: @user2771655 yes they are eligible but they may reside in memory until the GC does some work. This may never happen.

Comment: We need more information to help you further. How often it will be called? Is `MySecondClass` thread safe? Etc...

Comment: @AdamArold What do you mean by Thread safe? This class is calling more often. For example every 3 seconds one of those method is calling.

Comment: If you go with **Ex 1** then if you call for example `DoCount` while another thread runs `DoCount` as well they may interfere with each other.

Comment: @AdamArold  Well the second thread has another instance. It doesn't work on the same instance. So there is no mixup. These are not static methods

Comment: In **Ex 1** every thread uses the same instance of `MySecondClass`.

Comment: @zapl  I think the second way is more garbage friendly because it release the object once the method finish. But the first one holds it as long as the main object stays. If two threads use the instance of this class. thread one create a  MySecondClass instance and second thread also create a MySecondClass. So the object count is similler regardless of where it create.

Comment: @AdamArold I'm sorry whether my understanding of java is wrong. But in Ex 1, when ever we create a new instance of MyClass it creates a new instance of MySecondClass so how come it refers to the same instance of MySecondClass ?

Comment: You have a reference `var1`. Any object which calls a method on `MyClass` will use the same reference (`var1`).

Comment: @AdamArold   yes but not two objects call on the same MyClass. Each caller object/thread has its own instance of MyClass. Sorry if I confuse you with the example

Comment: @AdamArold     YES, But what's the wrong with the current code? As I said each thread has it's own instance of MyClass. So there will not be any over writing of MySecondClass instance. Different threads works on different instances of MyClass.

Comment: @user2771655 Ex2 produces way more garbage then Ex1 if you call those methods more than once. It makes AFAIK no difference for the GC where an Object to collect comes from, be it a local variable or some field. Objects from local variables are just simpler to detect as eligible to GC. Since GC (as well as object creation) takes time, you'd probably have better performance in Ex1. Or make the methods of `MySecondClass` `static` since both your examples look like they don't need an instance of some object (they don't seem to affect the state of that object, if they would Ex2 would not work).

Comment: @zapl I don't see any difference according to my example. If you see how I call them, Each time I create  new MyClass (). So it creates two separate MySecondClass objects (each at each time). No matter where MySecondClass reference declare. Right?

Comment: @user2771655 It does not matter if that's how you use them. You'll have 4 objects created and they are most likely not even garbage collected if your program ends directly after using them. On the other hand, that example looks like you don't need objects at all. If you create them just to have methods in a different place, think about `static` utility methods. For example `System.out.println()` does not require to do `new System()` each time because creating such an object would be pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, they will behave differently, after each method call (in Ex 2) *objects will be eligible for GC*, that though does not mean that they will get cleared after leaving the method immediately. In fact, memory will be reclaimed when GC actually runs, and this happens when there is pressure for the memory either in the young gen or old gen.

If your object creation is cheap and this object is small enough, then most probably you would not even feel that garbage collection occurred (since it is going to happen in the young generation). Unless you are sure that this is the bottle-neck in your application, then move the object as a instance field.

**Personal note**

I *would* go for the in-method approach as this would add thread safety and you never know where your class will be used in the future.